# React native node modules directory android native module code call in ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When we run npx react-native run-ios and goto screen input screen following error occurs. Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "AndroidTextInput" was not found in the UIManager. iOS Terminal.

[image]

```
$ watchman watch-del-all &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* &&
rm -rf node_modules/ &&
yarn cache clean &&
yarn install &&
yarn start -- --reset-cache
```